# GLFW + Vulkan on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, glfw, vulkan

I am setting up GLFW and Vulkan for a project of mine. For Vulkan I am using MoltenVk to get Vulkan compat and GLFW for the window creation. The IDE I am using is CLion, which uses the CMake system.

Judging from some github issues, there seems to be support for this setup, but nobody there mentions how it is done.

GLFW is installed through homebrew and MoltenVK manually by adding the MoltenVK and vulkan folders to usr/local/include and the contents of the MacOS folder to usr/local/lib (even though I am quite sure MoltenVK.framework should not be there).

At this point, Clion can see the GLFW and Vulkan headers, but I still need to link them up properly.

the full CMakeLists.txt file is this now:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(VulkanEngine)

#set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} “${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules”)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)
add_executable(VulkanEngine ${SOURCE_FILES})

#Finding and linking GLFW3

find_package(glfw3 3.2 REQUIRED)
if (glfw3_FOUND)
    include_directories(${glfw3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries (VulkanEngine ${glfw3_LIBRARIES})
endif (glfw3_FOUND)

#Finding and linking Vulkan

find_package (Vulkan)
if (Vulkan_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries (VulkanEngine ${Vulkan_LIBRARIES})
endif (Vulkan_FOUND)
```

the console tells the following when the cmake project has been reloading:

```
-- Could NOT find Vulkan (missing:  Vulkan_LIBRARY) 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/mtesseract/dev/cpp/VulkanEngine/cmake-build-debug
```

to me this indicates that GLFW has been found and linked, but when I try to build the "hello world" for GLFW, I get the following message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glfwInit", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
```

I got FindVulkan.cmake from the GLFW github page https://git.io/v5ggN, since it has support for MoltenVK, but I am not sure if it is picked up by CMake at all. (I put the file in (projectroot)/cmake/modules/)

At this point, I am out of ideas as to why things are not linking properly, so help is appreciated.

Comment: To find your FindVulkan.cmake you need to set CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to include the `cmake/modules/` . You have the line in your CMakeList.txt but it is commented out so you have to uncomment that.

Comment: Also, are you sure that `find_package(glfw3)` sets `glfw3_FOUND` variable and not `GLFW3_FOUND` one? It depends on the find script you have, and such scripts usually document variables they set.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I didn't explicitly specify the script anywhere, and with the change you told, I do get the script to pass the GLFW3_FOUND statement (Tested with the MESSAGE command). The strange thing though, is that it still says that _glfwInit is an undefined symbol.

Comment: @Eelke I disabled that yet Vulkan does not get found, since if I add the REQUIRED parameter to find_package(Vulkan) it errors out. Do you have any idea how I should prep the libraries for MoltenVK to properly be picked up?

Comment: As script sets `GLFW3_FOUND` variable, it probably sets `GLFW3_LIBRARIES` and so (prefix is in upper case). So you need to update your other commands too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I did so, didn't change much

Comment: @MTesseracT, yes it is disabled my point was that it should be enabled otherwise it won't look in your directory and it will use the FindVulkan.cmake provided by cmake. The one provided by cmake https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindVulkan.cmake seems to expect a VULKAN_SDK environment variable.

Comment: Vulkan is available on OSX??

Comment: @Eelke This is the situation right now: 
https://i.imgur.com/WvowBAx.png

The FindVulkan.cmake is a modified version that can be found in the GLFW git repo, it does seem to look for moltenVK on OSX, not sure how the lines that do this work though (I just recognize the names)
https://i.imgur.com/5PRFc83.png

Comment: @AntoineMorrier not exactly, but it is made available though MoltenVK, it's a type of compat layer that from what I understand, basically gives Vulkan handles to Metal.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I should have been a little more clear I changed the variable names (as you can see in my message to Eelke) and it does seem to find this. The strange thing is that the code still throws these undefined symbol errors.

Comment: If something has been changed, **update the question post**. Stack Overflow wants a question post to contain actual information about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that at least till some degree seems to work. At this point I have another problem to take care of (GLFW doesn't seem to pick up on MoltenVK's presence).

The process thus far is as follows (and can be found on my github page (github.com/mtesseracttech/VulkanEngine):

```
Vulkan + GLFW + GLM Setup Process with CMake and Package Managers

Windows:

Preparation:
Create CLion Application Project 
Install MSYS2 (Cygwin-like package manager that includes a windows port of Arch's PacMan)
Install LunarG VK SDK
Download FindVulkan.cmake from GFLW's Github (it includes a path for MoltenVK(for OSX Later)) and put it in (proj_root/cmake/modules)

MSYS2 Commands:

$ pacman -Su //Updates pacman
$ pacman -Ss {packageName} //Is used for searching for exact package names

Installed Packages through msys2:

$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain //Installs the CLion toolchain that includes CMake, Make, GCC, etc.
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-glfw //Installs GLFW
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-glm //Installs GLM
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-vulkan //Vulkan can also be installed through this method, but I went with LunarG

Enter the following in the CMakeLists.txt file in the root of the project:

######################################################################################

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(VulkanEngine)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)
add_executable(VulkanEngine ${SOURCE_FILES})

#Setting up PkgConfig

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

#Finding and linking GLFW3

pkg_search_module(GLFW3 3.2 REQUIRED glfw3)
if(GLFW3_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Found GLFW, Including and Linking now")
    include_directories(${GLFW3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(VulkanEngine ${GLFW3_STATIC_LIBRARIES})
endif(GLFW3_FOUND)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules/")

#Finding and linking Vulkan

find_package (Vulkan)
if (VULKAN_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Found Vulkan, Including and Linking now")
    include_directories(${VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries (VulkanEngine ${VULKAN_LIBRARY})
endif (VULKAN_FOUND)

######################################################################################




OSX:

Preparation

Create CLion Application Project 
Install HomeBrew (package manager)
Download MoltenVK
Download FindVulkan.cmake from GFLW's Github (it includes a path for MoltenVK(for OSX Later)) and put it in (proj_root/cmake/modules)

Homebrew:
brew update //Updates homebrew
brew install glfw //Installs GLFW
brew install glm //Installs GLM

MoltenVK:
Place MoltenVK/macOS's contents into /usr/local/lib
Place MoltenVK/macOS/MoltenVK.framework/headers's contents into /usr/local/inc/MoltenVK

CMake: 
Same as on windows, but in the FindVulkan.cmake file, add at the very end of the elseif(APPLE) block the line:
set(VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/local/include/MoltenVK")
This is not a pretty or flexible solution, but for now it will do.
```

I am pretty sure this solution is not ideal since GLFW isn't picking up on MoltenVK with this tactic, but at least things compile, so I see that as progress.

Comment: This isn't a good answer to your issue, you should not need msys2 to get this to work.  Your original error message was a missing definition for `_glfwInit`, which has less to do with Vulkan and more to do with GLFW.

Comment: Can you verify with `MESSAGE` that `glfw3_LIBRARIES` is a non-empty string?  Also, how exactly does `main.cpp` include the GLFW headers? Via `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems your issue is that you haven’t defined the `VULKAN_SDK`  variable. Make sure you point this to the parent folder of /lib & /include inside the SDK and FindVulkan should work

`VULKAN_SDK=/opt/vulkan/x86_64 cmake.`